# How to get the last time crash from windows phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can i get the last time crash (Exception) from windows phone 7 application
I am using C# in my application.

Comment: Do you log them anywhere yourself? I don't think WP7 logs anything like the desktop version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may come as a surprise to some, but applications sometimes crash. Even mine! On WP7 when an app has an unhandled exception it is killed by the operating system and you, the developer, will be none the wiser. However if you would like to know when your app died, and ideally why, here is some code

Reference from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2010/11/01/error-reporting-on-windows-phone-7.aspx)

```
namespace YourApp
{
    public class LittleWatson
    {
        const string filename = "LittleWatson.txt";

        internal static void ReportException(Exception ex, string extra)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    SafeDeleteFile(store);
                    using (TextWriter output = new StreamWriter(store.CreateFile(filename)))
                    {
                        output.WriteLine(extra);
                        output.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        output.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        internal static void CheckForPreviousException()
        {
            try
            {
                string contents = null;
                using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (store.FileExists(filename))
                    {
                        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)))
                        {
                            contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        SafeDeleteFile(store);
                    }
                }
                if (contents != null)
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("A problem occurred the last time you ran this application. Would you like to send an email to report it?", "Problem Report", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                    {
                        EmailComposeTask email = new EmailComposeTask();
                        email.To = "someone@example.com";
                        email.Subject = "YourAppName auto-generated problem report";
                        email.Body = contents;
                        SafeDeleteFile(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()); // line added 1/15/2011
                        email.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                SafeDeleteFile(IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());
            }
        }

        private static void SafeDeleteFile(IsolatedStorageFile store)
        {
            try
            {
                store.DeleteFile(filename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```